# What's the difference between an opcode and an operator?

Tags: operator-keyword, opcode

I'm a GCSE student studying Computing under the exam board, OCR. I have read these two words used interchangeably by OCR sometimes. Do these mean the same thing or are they different and how?

Comment: Is just reading the description of the 2 tags you gave your question enough to clarify it?

Comment: No. I don't understand 'In several languages, the operator keyword is used to identify methods which will be used in operator overloading'. Nor do I understand the definition of an opcode.

Comment: Defining operators is mostly syntactic sugar which changes the order of a function name and its arguments. Compare: ``let add a b = a + b`` and ``let (+) = add``, with respect to: 1. ``let y = add 5 3`` and 2. ``let y = 5 + 3``. Here, it is said that we defined operator ``(+)``, which is nothing but a function with special syntax. Op codes on the other hand denote the binary code of machine code instructions. ``LDA #00`` in 6502 assembler is eventually equivalent to the machine code ``A0 00``. ``A0`` being the op code for ``Load accumulator -> LDA``.

Comment: So an operator is a symbol (+, -, x, etc.) while an opcode represents binary instructions? I don't know... I'm still quite confused.

Comment: If someone builds a new CPU, the CPU needs an instruction set, operating on memory and registers etc. From that instruction set, a single instruction is identified by an OP code (and some other stuff, like addressing modes,..). So, in a manual about a CPU, you will likely find a list of instructions along with their binary encoding. Part of which is the opcode of an instruction. Operators, on the other hand are a construct in a programming language.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Thanks.